# Modified Double Slit (Screen at right angle)

Tags: experimental-physics, double-slit-experiment, interference, experimental-technique

I have prepared a setup similar to the original double slit experience with a little adjustment, I carefully traced out all the paths after particles exits the slits. Then I place 2 screens at right angle to each other where they meets exactly at the boundary where both trajectories would meet.

If I closes slit 2 and run the experiment, I know the particle went through slit-1 and vice versa.

Will this setup produce interference pattern? If so how is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Note that behind a single slit as well as behind every sharp edge an intensity distribution occur. Even if photons were sent one after one the fringes are present statistically after some time.  BTW the experiment is brilliant. Hope it will be realized.

Comment: "I have prepared a setup". Did you really and will we see the results? Would be nice to get the results, please.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the angles of your drawing you cannot get double slit Interference because light from either slit can't reach the opposite side to interfere.